# How can I fetch value from CoreData to Variable?

Tags: swiftui, nsfetchrequest

**CoreData:**

Item

- userName
- userSurname

**Fetch request**

```
@FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
```

How can I apply last added `userName` in `Items` value to
`var X` ?

Comment: `items` contains multiple records. You have to specify which record you want.

Comment: Last added in Items

Comment: _"How can I apply userName value to var X ?"_ Can you give more details? What is `var x`? Please ready [mcve] and update your question.

Comment: According to your sort descriptor the last added item is the last element:  `var x = items.last?.userName ?? ""`

Comment: @vadian thank you! Can you add your solution as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @vadian

`var x = items.last?.userName ?? ""`